# Empty Topology?

Tags: general-topology

I am familiar with the topology on the empty set , Is there a space let's say with the set $R$ where non of its subsets are open ? If it does it will apply that all of them are close no ? and that countable union of them will be close too , which means that this is not a topological space ?

Comment: The space itself must always be open.

Comment: Towards your second question "not open" does not imply "closed".

Comment: Also, it is possible, for certain topologies, that a countably infinite union of closed sets is closed (take an infinite set and declare all subsets to be open, for example; this is the so-called *discrete* topology).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a set $X$ with topology $\tau$, these must be fulfilled (fulfilling these is what it *means* for $\tau$ to be a topology)

1. Any element of $\tau$ is a subset of $X$.
2. $X\in \tau$ and $\emptyset \in \tau$.
3. For any $U, V \in \tau$, we must have $U\cap V \in \tau$.
4. For any $\mathscr U \subseteq \tau$, we must have $\left(\bigcup_{U \in \mathscr U}U\right) \in \tau$.

We see that $\tau = \{X, \emptyset\}$ is the smallest possible topology on any set $X$, since $2$ has to be fulfilled. It's usually called the trivial topology.

Also, as for the connection between open and closed sets, it is not the case that non-open sets are closed. It's rather that the *complement* of any open set is closed (and vice versa). So the whole set and the empty set are by definition also closed. If these are the two *only* subsets of $X$ to be both open and closed ("clopen"), then we say that $X$ is *connected*. So there is no contradiction or disjunction between openness and closedness. They are two different things that may or may not be fulfilled for any given subset. In fact, sets being both at the same time are an important part of general topology.

Comment: Thanks and sory for this stupid question